# Using frequency to turn a circuit on

Tags: audio, switches, frequency

I would like to run 3 circuits and turn them on based on a frequency input from an audio source. I would like to turn on a circuit at a mosfet gate for example with tone A at 100Hz tone, B with 1kHz, and C with 10kHz.

I this this may be possible with 3x band/low/high pass filters of some find but in my modelling I seem to have residual talk from the different channels/frequencies.
Is there a way to achieve this with simple analog electronics?

Comment: You need to decide what amount of frequency error you will tolerate. Should 105 Hz be close enough to 100 Hz to turn on circuit A? 101 Hz? And realize that the narrower you make the band, the longer it will take to discriminate the desired frequency from a nearby undesired frequency, so the response of the circuit will be slower.

Comment: yeah that's why i am aiming for 100, 1k, 10k as they should be far enough apart. let's aim for <10% error.

Comment: It's been many years since I've used one but it looks like the LM567 is still available, maybe something like that would be suitable?

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly simple task for a DSP (Digital Signal Processor) such as the Microchip dsPIC family.  The [DSPIC33FJ32GP102](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000652f.pdf) for example, with 32KB of flash and 2KB RAM, [costs $3.19 in single quantities](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1291=6302&k=dsPIC33FJ32GP102&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) in a simple to use DIP package.

The most efficient way to detect tones like this is to use the [Goertzel algorithm](http://www.embedded.com/design/real-world-applications/4401754/Single-tone-detection-with-the-Goertzel-algorithm).

Microchip provides a library for the dsPIC processors [for detecting DTMF frequencies](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70332B.pdf) which I have successfully used in a project.  It uses the Goertzel algorithm to detect two simultaneous tones, selected from 16 frequencies spaced fairy close together (a few hundred Hz).  So your situation is even simpler since you only need to look for one tone (or you can use it as is for DTMF).  The [full source code](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en536955) for the library is provided so you can modify it per your needs, including Goertzel.s.

As set up, the library uses a tolerance of ±1.5% to validate the frequencies (±1.5 Hz for the 100 Hz tone, ±15 Hz for 1 kHz,  and ±150 Hz for 10 kHz); and 40 ms minimum to detected a tone.  These parameters should be fairly easy to modify.

The 1.5% percent is would be necessary if you were to stick with DTMF tones, since they are fairly close together (hundreds of Hz), but if you were to use your propsed 100 Hz, 1kHz and 10kHz then ±10% should be doable.

[Here's a project](https://www2.ia-engineers.org/iciae/index.php/icisip/icisip2013/paper/viewFile/247/184) someone did to detect ambulance sirens using a dsPIC.  (It used FFT instead of Goertzel but still an interesting read.)

Note that if you don't already have a circuit for generating the tones, you can use a second dsPIC for that.  Microchip has a DTMF send library in addition to the DTMF receive which you could modify (either to use as is for DTMF, or modify for a single tone).

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a frequency to voltage converter: -

[image]

Then adding window comparators to produce enable outputs at the three frequencies needed.

The values in the circuit above may not be ideal for the frequency range you are looking at so some tweaking may be necessary. There are other ways of converting frequency to voltage so I'd encourage you to google the possibilities (maybe the [LM2917](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2917.pdf) or the [ADVFC32](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADVFC32.pdf). The AD part can cope with a range from virtually DC to 500 kHz.

Answer (score 1):

It would likely be easier to do this with a DSP, but in the spirit of the question there is a simple discrete solution based on the architecture you described above.

I am not completely clear what behavior you are looking for at the in-between frequencies but I will assume you want exactly one of the circuits on at all times. Therefore I suggest the following tweak on your plan:

[image: cir]

By having only two filters and comparators, I can then post-process with logic gates to get the desired behavior.

The envolope detectors are just [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use specific frequencies, consider using DTMF (Dual Tone Multi Frequency) ICs used for telephone signalling. They incorporate multiple frequency generators clocked to a (typically) 3.579545 MHz crystal. They've gotten harder to find since there are more modern ways of signalling remotely, but the surplus shops still carry DTMF encoders and decoders. I see Jameco has the TCM5089 on closeout for $4.95. An example of a corresponding detector would be the SSI202 from Silicon Systems. I believe it was multiply sourced.

There were also versions of the generators that were designed to be controlled from a microprocessor as opposed to a keypad.

Going a bit further, I'm sure that there is code out there for the popular microcontrollers to do the same thing, but I've never had to use it.